# Unable to load resources from thread context class loader?

Tags: java

I am trying to get the complete file path of a resource in a java project that was given to me. The code fails to find the file by using the filename only. I need help to make it work.

This is the project structure:

[image]

**This is the code**:

```
package com.testing.software.apps;

public class FileTest {

    public static void main(String[]args) {
        String fileName = "orders-2017.txt";
        String filePath = getFilePath(fileName);
        System.out.println("File path is: " + filePath);
    }

    public static String getFilePath(String fileName) {
        String fullFilepath = Thread.currentThread().
                getContextClassLoader().
                getResource(fileName).
                getPath();
        return fullFilepath;
    }

}
```

This code throws a null pointer exception in the "getPath();" line. I figured out that the exception occurs because this line "getResource(fileName)" returns a null URL object. Upon inspecting the getResource code, I see that finally "url = findResource(name);" returns null.

```
public URL getResource(String name) {
    URL url;
    if (parent != null) {
        url = parent.getResource(name);
    } else {
        url = getBootstrapResource(name);
    }
    if (url == null) {
        url = findResource(name);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Looking at the definition of java.net.URL findResource, I see that it always returns null, thereby giving me a null all the time.

```
protected URL findResource(String name) {
    return null;
}
```

Can someone please explain why this code always ends up giving null and how I can make it find the file by only using the filename?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ClassLoader is an abstract class. The method findResource returns null in default implementation. In runtime there should be used and implementation of this class that overrides this method.

```
/**
     * Finds the resource with the given name. Class loader implementations
     * should override this method to specify where to find resources.
     *
     * @param  name
     *         The resource name
     *
     * @return  A <tt>URL</tt> object for reading the resource, or
     *          <tt>null</tt> if the resource could not be found
     *
     * @since  1.2
     */
    protected URL findResource(String name) {
        return null;
    }
```

You get errror because you are using wrong path. You should add directories since the method does not goes recursively through resource directory. Try with `fileName = "text-files/orders/orders-2017.txt";`

If you are using default maven path configuration and if you want to use this resource in main function you should move them to src/main/resources.

If you want to keep them in src/test/java then they will be only available from classes that are in src/test/java directory.

Comment: Further reading https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/

Comment: Is the code in my post a good, platform independent way to find files inside a project or is there a better approach ? I tried to use buffered reader as shown in example 2 over here. https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-text-file-line-by-line/ I used the file path = ".\\src\test\\resources\\text-files\\orders\\orders-2017.txt" and it works fine and there is no null pointer. But, I am not sure if this approach is better. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You can simply use Paths.get("text-files/orders/orders-2017.txt") to get path object. I recommend reading more about Path class in java. Maven will look for file in default location which is src/main/resources for regular code and src/test/resources for test cases.